# Do objects gets destroyed properly with kill?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, object

In the following, the child process creates the object. It uses signal to kill itself after certain period of time:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Wut{
public:
  Wut(){cout<<"obj being created" << endl;}
  ~Wut(){cout<<"obj being destroyeed" << endl;} 
};

void alarmHandler(){
   cout << "Alarm! Forcing child to kill itself" << endl;
   kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   int status;
   pid_t pid;
   if((pid = fork()) == 0){
      Wut hi;
      signal(SIGALRM, (sighandler_t)alarmHandler);
      alarm(1);
      alarm(7);
      sleep(10);
      cout << "this will not get printed" << endl;
   } else {
      wait(&status);
      cout << "Parent dies" << endl;
   }
   sleep(10);
   return 0;
}
```

But I am not sure if the object it creates gets destroyed properly because it never calls the destructor.

Comment: Perhaps not "properly" destroyed, but they are gone none the less. You are using a bazooka and ask if the target is properly destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

The KILL signal is actually not sent to the process; it's a signal for the operating system to forcibly stop the program execution. That means that destructors will not be called.

Use a signal like `SIGTERM` to see the expected behaviour:

```
kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unix processes can't handle `SIGKILL` in any way.  Your process is dead as a doornail, immediately.  If you want a graceful exit, look into `SIGTERM`.  You can then register a handler to do whatever cleanup you need.

You can use the handler to put your program into a state where it exits normally (e.g. by setting a flag or such), allowing the destructors to run.

Answer (score 0):

`SIGKILL` is (in most cases) the same as `kill -9`, so all of the memory allocated to that process is reclaimed by the operating system.